# Best way to upgrade an Angular 2.0.0-rc.4 application

Tags: angular

I have recently started on a project that is on Angular 2.0.0-rc.4 For some reason it was not upgraded in time. I don't find enough help online.

What would be the best approach to upgrade this kind of project.
I was think of doing it in increments RC4 to RC5 (because there is some help on this), then 2 final and then 4.

Ultimate goal is to upgrade to latest Angular version.
Any links or docs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of a *painless* way to do this. Incrementing RC4, RC5, 2 and 4 would take a lot of wasted time, I think, because the same thing may have changed twice.

I've faced situations like this a couple times (in fact I am *right now*, migrating an old project from old C++ to C++17), so the only honest advice I can give is what I do. For your Angular project, it would be:

1. Start a fresh new project which works, be comfortable with any new stuff you see;
2. Create the first module;
3. Put the first component from old project into the new. Start with the component that has less dependencies;
4. Go to step 3 until you have a minimally functional project, eventually creating the other modules for other components.

Unless you have unusual component interactions, this process should be fairly manageable, but potentially *tedious* if you have many components.

Also, to keep it up to latest version, you should go to [Angular 5](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced), not 4.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the upgrade tool? https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: This looks like upgrades from 2 final to higher versions?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18178087)

Comment: @anacron, did you look at the page? It's an upgrade tool.